# Revert to previous version of Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods

Due to some crash happening in current version of **Firebase** `Firebase/Core (6.20.0)`, I want to revert to a previous version of **Firebase** `Firebase/Core (6.15.0)` that was working for my project. Is there a way to revert to previous version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the version you want to use to the line in your Podfile:

```
pod "Firebase/Core", "= 6.15.0"
```

and run `pod install`.